# Rspec 'cannot load such file'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I am doing the Testing with Rspec course of Code School and have installed ruby 2.2.1, rails 4.2.5.1 and rspec 3.4.4 to my Ubuntu system. As the first video describes I typed

```
rspec --init
```

in my project folder, which created a spec folder, in which i made a new directory called lib. There i placed the both .rb files:

```
touch spec/lib/zombie_spec.rb
touch spec/lib/zombie.rb
```

The spec_helper.rb is created normally in the spec folder.
If i run:

```
rspec spec/lib/zombie_spec.rb
```

for the following code in zombie_spec.rb:

```
require "spec_helper"
describe "Zombie" do
    it "is named Ash"
end
```

everything runs as expected and shown in the video.
But if i take the next step and add

```
require "zombie"
```

to the zombie_spec.rb file after the first require, I get the error:

```
cannot load such file -- zombie (LoadError)
```

zombie.rb looks exactly like this:

```
class Zombie
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zombie.rb` should be located in `{project_home}/lib/` as pointed out by @kclowes.

In your case since it lives in the same folder (not recommended), you should use the format: `require './zombie'` and not `require 'zombie'` because the latter is used for standard and/or third party libraries.

This question is months old but I am answering in case somebody stumbles upon this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Typically you don't want your `zombie.rb` inside your spec folder since it's not a test file, but I'm not familiar with the Code School tutorials. RSpec does some magic with file paths so it might be looking in the wrong spot.

You might try either `require_relative "./zombie"` or move `zombie.rb` outside of your spec file and `require "<path_to_zombie>/zombie"`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to kclowes answer you can add directories to your autoload paths within the rails configuration so that they're automatically `require`d when Rails loads.

To do this simply add

`config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/spec/lib"`

to `config/test.rb`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to require a file in exactly one other file, this is another possibility:

```
require "#{::Rails.root}/spec/support/models/shared_examples/<my_file>"
```

(Rails 6.0.x)